# Facebook Login with Codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I am trying to put Facebook Login button on Codeigniter platform.

I have followed this procedure

http://www.dannyherran.com/2011/02/facebook-php-sdk-and-codeigniter-for-basic-user-authentication/

but I got this error

```
API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: Requires valid redirect URI.
```

I used exactly same code that the website provided.

Can you tell me why I get this error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set valid redirect_uri ?

```
'redirect_uri' => ''
```